# CSS selector for child of EITHER parent A or B (best practice)?

Tags: css, css-selectors

In short, I'd like to select a child element that has **either** Parent A **or** Parent B.

I'm wondering if there's a way to simplify my selectors in this scenario, or if what I have here is the only way to do it.  Also, is there a best practice in this scenario?  Below are some simplified examples:

```
/* long example (probably not best practice) */
    #parent-a .common-child {
        color: #000;
    }
    #parent-b .common-child {
        color: #000;
    }

/* shortest example I know of */
    #parent-a .common-child, #parent-b .common-child {
        color: #000;
    }
```

Is there any way to do something like:

```
#parent-a||#parent-b .common-child {
    color: #000;
}
```

It might not look like a big deal in these simple examples, but in my actual CSS I have several dozen selectors that chain down through the DOM a bit, and I want to optimize the file size / readability.

Thanks!

Comment: Not without [LESS](http://lesscss.org/), or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/), as I recall. Otherwise your posted shortest example *is* the shortest means of achieving your aims.

Comment: This has been asked so many times, and I'm not just referring to the "is there a selector for this?" part. The problem is that the duplicate questions are so badly-phrased that even I am hard-pressed to find any good canonical question to link to.

Comment: BoltClock - Sorry, I tried to search as best as I could.  Would you mind referring me to some of those Q&As?  And maybe what terms you used to search for them so I can get better at that?

Comment: Point taken; I edited my comment.

Comment: @DavidThomas How would you do it with SASS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/* shortest example I know of */
#parent-a .common-child, #parent-b .common-child {
    color: #000;
}
```

This would be the most simplified solution. They have to be separated. All you can do is combine similar styles into one line like in the above.

However, I would say that you're almost leaving the realm of use for an ID selector. An ID is meant to be unique, and the styles that apply to it should be unique as well. If you ever add a `parent-c` or further, you should definitely consider adding a single class to those elements rather than selecting each one by its ID.

`color: #000` is a very broad style. If that were the only style being applied to both of these elements, it would make sense to set the style on a parent higher up so that it gets inherited by all its children, grandchildren, and so on.

Without seeing more of your structure, we can't really advise you on best practices. CSS and its optimization is very highly based on what else is around it and being specific.

Comment: Thanks.  Yep, the real CSS isn't doing anything this simplistic.  Basically I'm wanting to define styles once for two different contexts (one is the front end of a WordPress theme, and the other context is the tinyMCE editor in edit mode).  Unfortunately both have a different common parent body.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no shorter way to do it than your last example.

Answer (score 0):

In Sass this can be done with the [Sass Ampersand](https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/):

```
parent1, parent2 { 
    & .common-child {
        color: #000;
    }
}
```